# Firebase Session Management: Issues with instatiating Global User

Tags: java, android, firebase, session, authentication

I'm a Android Studio coding beginner and currently building a nutrition app to get programming practice. I use Firebase for Authentication and as a database to save User data.

**How it works:**

My app has a survey built in which asks for body specifics and taste (age, height, liked/disliked ingredients etc.). I have a class GlobalUser with public static attributes to save the answers in the app. When the user registers, he is sent directly to the survey activity. There he answers the questions and the results are written to the Firebase database under his UID (I use a User class with the same attributes as GlobalUser to create an instance and use Firebase's setValue(Object) method). If he signs in (or still is signed in), the LoginRegistrationActivity directly sends him to the MainActivity. There, the GlobalUser class gets instantiated with the data saved under his UID. From the MainActivity, he can navigate to a ProfileActivity where the UI gets updated based on his data. This works quite well. After doing the survey I can find the results in a child node consisting of the UID of the user, the UI gets updated correctly and the sign in/registration process works as intended.

**What is wrong:**

However, as I was playing around with different designs and constantly restarting the app, it started to crash occasionally. After some testing it showed that the GlobalUser class wasn't updated and thus the ArrayLists were null and caused NullPointerExceptions when I used .size() on them. Since this issue only occurs rarely and seems to be related to restarting the app multiple times I thought it would have something to do with the Activity lifecycle so I also updated the GlobalUser in onStart and onResume but it didn't help. I also tried updating GlobalUser again in the ProfileActivity directly before the ArrayLists were set but it didn't work. I still guess it has something to do with the lifecycle but I have no idea where I should start. Here's the code of the relevant classes/actvitites:

LoginRegistrationActivity:

```
public class LoginRegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference mRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private EditText emailAddress;
    private EditText emailPassword;
    private Button emailLogin;
    private Button emailRegistration;
    private TextView forgotPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_registration);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
            Intent i = new Intent (LoginRegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            LoginRegistrationActivity.this.startActivity(i);
        }

        emailAddress = findViewById(R.id.address_edit);
        emailPassword = findViewById(R.id.password_edit);
        emailLogin = findViewById(R.id.mail_login_button);
        emailRegistration = findViewById(R.id.mail_registration_button);
        forgotPassword = findViewById(R.id.forgot_password);

        emailRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = emailAddress.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = emailPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginRegistrationActivity.this, "Bitte E-Mail Addresse eingeben!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginRegistrationActivity.this, "Bitte Passwort eingeben!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (password.length()<6){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginRegistrationActivity.this, "Passwort muss mindestens sechs Zeichen lang sein!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(LoginRegistrationActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginRegistrationActivity.this, "Unbekannter Fehler", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Intent i = new Intent (LoginRegistrationActivity.this, SurveyGreetingActivity.class);
                            LoginRegistrationActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        emailLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String password = emailPassword.getText().toString();
                String email = emailAddress.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginRegistrationActivity.this, "Bitte E-Mail Addresse eingeben!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginRegistrationActivity.this, "Bitte Passwort eingeben!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (password.length()<6){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginRegistrationActivity.this, "Passwort muss mindestens sechs Zeichen haben!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(LoginRegistrationActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginRegistrationActivity.this, "Unbekannter Fehler beim Einloggen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Intent i = new Intent (LoginRegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            LoginRegistrationActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference mRef = database.getReference().child("users").child("uid").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());


        //In case the user cancelled the app when filling out the survey for the first time
        if (mRef == null){
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this, SurveyGreetingActivity.class));
        }

        //sets GlobalUser to data saved in Firebase Database User object
        mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user!=null){
                    GlobalUser.setToUser(user);
                    GlobalUser.setGlobalUid(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

GlobalUser:

```
package com.example.andre.valetto02;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class GlobalUser {

    public static String globalUid = null;

    public static ArrayList<Ingredient> globalLikes;

    public static ArrayList<Ingredient> globalDislikes;

    public static int globalAge;

    public static int globalWeight;

    public static int globalHeight;

    public static int globalTrainingGoal;

    public static int globalDailyActive;

    public static boolean globalIsMale;

    public GlobalUser() {
    }

    public static String getGlobalUid() {
        return globalUid;
    }

    public static void setGlobalUid(String globalUid) {
        GlobalUser.globalUid = globalUid;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Ingredient> getGlobalLikes() {
       return globalLikes;
    }

    public static void setGlobalLikes(ArrayList<Ingredient> globalLikes) {
        GlobalUser.globalLikes = globalLikes;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Ingredient> getGlobalDislikes() {
        return globalDislikes;
    }

    public static void setGlobalDislikes(ArrayList<Ingredient> globalDislikes) {
        GlobalUser.globalDislikes = globalDislikes;
    }

    public static int getGlobalAge() {
        return globalAge;
    }

    public static void setGlobalAge(int globalAge) {
        GlobalUser.globalAge = globalAge;
    }

    public static int getGlobalWeight() {
        return globalWeight;
    }

    public static void setGlobalWeight(int globalWeight) {
        GlobalUser.globalWeight = globalWeight;
    }

    public static int getGlobalHeight() {
        return globalHeight;
    }

    public static void setGlobalHeight(int globalHeight) {
        GlobalUser.globalHeight = globalHeight;
    }

    public static int getGlobalTrainingGoal() {
        return globalTrainingGoal;
    }

    public static void setGlobalTrainingGoal(int globalTrainingGoal) {
        GlobalUser.globalTrainingGoal = globalTrainingGoal;
    }

    public static int getGlobalDailyActive() {
        return globalDailyActive;
    }

    public static void setGlobalDailyActive(int globalDailyActive) {
        GlobalUser.globalDailyActive = globalDailyActive;
    }

    public static boolean isGlobalIsMale() {
        return globalIsMale;
    }

    public static void setGlobalIsMale(boolean globalIsMale) {
        GlobalUser.globalIsMale = globalIsMale;
    }

    public static void setToUser(User user) {
       GlobalUser.setGlobalAge(user.getAge());
       GlobalUser.setGlobalWeight(user.getWeight());
       GlobalUser.setGlobalHeight(user.getHeight());
       GlobalUser.setGlobalDailyActive(user.getDailyActive());
       GlobalUser.setGlobalTrainingGoal(user.getTrainingGoal());
       GlobalUser.setGlobalIsMale(user.getIsMale());
       GlobalUser.setGlobalLikes(user.getLikes());
       GlobalUser.setGlobalDislikes(user.getDislikes());
   }

   public static void resetLikesAndDislikes(){
       globalLikes = new ArrayList <>();
       globalDislikes = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   public static User globalToUser () {
       return new User (globalLikes, globalDislikes, globalWeight, globalHeight, globalAge, globalTrainingGoal, globalDailyActive, globalIsMale);
    }
}
```

User:

```
package com.example.andre.valetto02;
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class User {
    ArrayList<Ingredient> likes;
    ArrayList<Ingredient> dislikes;

    Boolean isMale;

    public Boolean getIsMale(){return isMale;}

    public void setIsMale(Boolean b){isMale = b;}

    public void setDislikes(ArrayList<Ingredient> dislikes) {
        this.dislikes = dislikes;
    }


    public User (){
        likes = new ArrayList<>();
        dislikes = new ArrayList<>();
        weight = 0;
        height = 0;
        age = 0;
        trainingGoal = 2;
        dailyActive = 1;
        isMale=true;
    }

    public User (ArrayList<Ingredient> l, ArrayList<Ingredient> d, int w, int h, int a, int tG, int dA, boolean iM) {
        likes = l;
        dislikes = d;
        weight = w;
        height = h;
        age = a;
        trainingGoal = tG;
        dailyActive = dA;
        isMale = iM;
    }

    int age;

    public ArrayList<Ingredient> getDislikes() {
        return dislikes;
    }

    public ArrayList<Ingredient> getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public void setLikes (ArrayList<Ingredient> list){
        likes = list;
    }

    public void setDisikes (ArrayList<Ingredient> list){
        dislikes = list;
    }

    public int getAge () {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge (int i) {
        age = i;
    }

    int weight;

    public int getWeight (){
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int i) {
        weight = i;
    }

    int height;

    public int getHeight (){
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int i) {
        height = i;
    }

    int trainingGoal; //trainingGoal = 0 means weight loss, 1 means muscle gain and 2 means healthy living

    public void setTrainingGoal(int i) {
        trainingGoal = i;
    }

    public int getTrainingGoal(){
        return trainingGoal;
    }

    int dailyActive; //dailyActive = 0 means wenig, 1 means leicht, 2 means moderat, 3 means sehr and 4 means extrem

    public int getDailyActive() {return dailyActive;}

    public void setDailyActive(int i) {dailyActive = i;}

    public double computeCalorieGoal(){
        if (isMale) {
            double RMR;
            RMR = weight*10 + 6.25*height - 5*age + 5;
            if (dailyActive==0) {RMR=RMR*1.2;}
            else if (dailyActive==1) {RMR=RMR*1.375;}
            else if (dailyActive==2) {RMR=RMR*1.55;}
            else if (dailyActive==3) {RMR=RMR*1.725;}
            else {RMR=RMR*1.9;}
            if (trainingGoal == 0) {RMR = RMR - 400;}
            else if (trainingGoal ==1){RMR = RMR + 400;}
            return RMR;

        } else {
            double RMR;
            RMR = weight*10 + 6.25*height - 5*age - 161;
            if (dailyActive==0) {RMR=RMR*1.2;}
            else if (dailyActive==1) {RMR=RMR*1.375;}
            else if (dailyActive==2) {RMR=RMR*1.55;}
            else if (dailyActive==3) {RMR=RMR*1.725;}
            else {RMR=RMR*1.9;}
            if (trainingGoal == 0) {RMR = RMR - 300;}
            else if (trainingGoal ==1){RMR = RMR + 300;}
            return RMR;

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi André. Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow! Please try post the minimum code necessary to reproduce a specific issue. There are some great guidelines here. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Elletlar, I'll try to post it more compact next time. However, do you have any idea what the reason could be? I tried instantiating the attributes in the onStart, onResume, onRestart and onCreate methods but it didn't work. Sometimes you just need to close the app once and when you restart it, the error occurs when trying to open the ProfileActivity. It seems like the code that sets the attributes of the GlobalUser to the Datasnapshot just won't get executed. Is there any other lifecycle part that could help me?

Comment: No problem. If you post a lot of code like this it is too difficult to isolate the problem so people will move onto other posts that they can more readily understand. I would create a single activity that reproduces the problem and put the relevant code in a new post here. Also upload a minimal project with that activity to Github or Googledrive. It isn't usually necessary to provide a link to a running project, but I think you might have a better chance of getting an answer to this one if someone can actually run the code.

Comment: Just found the mistake myself (got to admit feel pretty proud of myself right now :D) but thanks for the advice! Will definitely follow it next time.

Comment: Np. Glad it is working :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

I just found the mistake. It has nothing to do with the activity lifecycle and it only indirectly had something to do with restarting the app. The problem was that Firebase's Value Event Listeners are still AsyncTasks. When I started the app and immediately opened the ProfileActivity, the Activity was created before the Firebase AsyncTask could fetch the data from the Database. Thus the ProfileActivity would call the .size() method on the ArrayLists before they were instantiated. In essence, the error occurred when you clicked too quickly through the UI and were faster than the asynchronous data fetching task.

Therefore I moved the session management to the LoginRegistrationActivity like this:

```
     if (mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference mRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users").child("uid").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        //In case the user cancelled the app when filling out the survey for the first time
        if (mRef == null){
            LoginRegistrationActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent (LoginRegistrationActivity.this, SurveyGreetingActivity.class));
        }
        mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user!=null) {
                    GlobalUser.setToUser(user);
                    GlobalUser.setGlobalUid(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                }
                Intent i = new Intent (LoginRegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                LoginRegistrationActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

By moving LoginRegistrationActivity.this.startActivity(i) to the onDataChange method, I ensure that the GlobalUser variables get instantiated before the MainActivity is started. There are probably still more elegant ways to do this.